# How to display Prince PCA Eigenvectors

Tags: pca

I am looking for a way to display the eigenvectors on the prince library. Could you please tell me what is the command as I am not finding it in the documentation (eigenvalues_ for eigenvalues) :)

Answer (score 0):

This is written on the [prince github page](https://github.com/kormilitzin/Prince):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

import prince


df = pd.read_csv('data/iris.csv')

pca = prince.PCA(df, n_components=4)

fig1, ax1 = pca.plot_cumulative_inertia()
fig2, ax2 = pca.plot_rows(color_by='class', ellipse_fill=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Not exactly, I am looking for the coordinates of the eigenvectors, not the representations of the differents entries in the eigenvectors coordinate system